# eyeD3 -- recursive Tag removal

Tags: recursion, metadata, id3, eyed3

I want to **recursively** remove all ID3v1/ID3v2-tags of my mp3-files with eyeD3.
Can't get it work.

The slim doc doesn't say much about the PATH-variable and its usage.

```
usage: eyeD3 [-h] [--version] [--exclude PATTERN]
             [--plugins] [--plugin NAME]
             [PATH [PATH ...]]
```

How to apply and use the PATH-variable correct?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [online documentation](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/cli.html)

> The PATH argument(s) along with optional usage of --exclude are used to tell eyeD3 what files or directories to process. 
>   Directories are searched **recursively** and every file encountered is passed to the plugin until no more files are found.

Are you sure, that the PATH-variable doesn't work this way?

Comment: I tried the PATH-Variable in different manners without any --exclude directives and neither worked. I'd appreciate a practical example. In particular the answer to the question how to interpret the nested braces around the [PATH [PATH]] option.